# running gdbserver in background debugging a program and connect to it with gdb from time to time

Tags: c, linux, gdb, gdbserver

I have written a program in C for an embedded device on a Debian-based linux.

One of the devices got a segmentation fault after 8 days running, so it is not a very frequent bug that I can track fast with gdb.

A few years ago I know that I used gdb (with gdbserver, I guess) running the program detached from the shell so I could leave the device running and check every day if something bad had happened, but I don't remember how I did that!

I have tried with gdbserver, connecting to it with gdb, but it stops debugging when I close the connection.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to `detach`, not quit gdb like that.

Since you're only in for post-mortems, anyway, I'd however recommend something completely different:

Enable core dumping; as root, run

```
 > sudo -s ##become root
 $ echo "*  soft  core  unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
 $ su -l <user that is running the crashing program>
 $ ulimit -c unlimited
 $ program 
 ##wait for crash
```

(that lifts any restriction, including the default 0B restriction, on the maximum core dump file size).

Then, after a crash, find the `core.*` coredump file, and open it with gdb. Voila, the state of the program when crashing is restored in gdb and you can do pretty much anything that you could do with a gdb attached at crash time.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I tried your solution and made some tests to confirm that the core dumps were generated but the real program's core dump was not generated (this time the segfault appeared after 13 days running). I think it is because it is a daemon and when I run it it becomes independent to the user's session that set up the ulimit parameter. I have tried to set kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
kernel.core_pattern = /tmp/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t
fs.suid_dumpable = 2  in /etc/sysctl.conf but still, if I log off and in again the core dump functionality dissapear.